# Openlayers 3 reloading the map after updating features

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm trying to add and move features on my map. These updates come through a form, so after the data has been updated I want to reload the map to see the changes. I've tried the old

```
map.updateSize();
```

but it's not actually updating the map. Is there some other way to force update the map or reload all layers?

Comment: Can you show where you're adding features? You should be using the api calls (i.e. `addFeature()`) to add features to the collection -- may be using the underlying array directly? -- in this case the collection might not be calling a change event, causing the map to never update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically I'm going over all the layers in the map and then updating the params of their source to force them to reload.

I am also using TypeScript, but you should be able to convert it to Javscript easily enough:

```
            let layers: ol.Collection<ol.layer.Base> = map.getLayers();

            layers.forEach((layer: ol.layer.Base) => {
                if (layer instanceof ol.layer.Group) {
                    var groupLayers = layer.getLayers();
                    groupLayers.forEach((item) => {
                        if (item instanceof ol.layer.Image) {
                            item as ol.layer.Image;
                            var source: any = item.getSource();
                            if (source.updateParams != undefined)
                                source.updateParams({ 'time': Date.now() });
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    if (layer instanceof ol.layer.Image) {
                        layer as ol.layer.Image;
                        var source: any = layer.getSource();
                        if (source.updateParams != undefined)
                            source.updateParams({ 'time': Date.now() });
                    }
                }
            });
```